# Accessing /etc directory using PHP's fopen command

Tags: php, fopen, file-permissions

I have a txt file that I need to access via fopen that is located at `/etc/company/lastID.txt` via the following script:

```
$dataFile = "/etc/company/lastID.txt";
$fh = fopen($dataFile, "r");

print_r(error_get_last());

$lastID = fread($fh, filesize($dataFile));
fclose($fh);
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
fopen(/etc/company/lastID.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

but the file is definitely there. When I call another file in the same directory using `require_once` it is read without issue, only when I use `fopen` do I seem to have a problem.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happen when you try to read another file in /etc/company directory? This error means file doesn't exits.

Comment: you were right, the directory structure wasn't correct on the machine and it needed to be modified. *Slaps self with a fish*